# How to draw true coordinates system in Blender without creating geometry

Tags: gizmo

I want to do a math animation using blender, so I need to create 3D coordinates including the X,Y,Z line, however, I can only create the axis by creating real geometry, like a very long cylinder to simulate the x,y,z axis, the disadvange is when zoom in and out, the axis will change and this is what I do not like, what I need to have is to draw x,y,z axis like the built gizmo, that looks the same independent of the view distance, and has its own color represent different axis.

Comment: I think you have the right term, unfortunately there isn't a lot of information on how to create blender gizmos out there. You'll have to use python to code it. You can take a look at the blender API https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Gizmo.html

Comment: yes, I will be using Python it is fine, I will take a look